# Android 5.0 display keeps turning on with black and white notifications

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, bugs, oneplus-one

I have an Oneplus One which just got its Android 5.0 version released.
It is known that there are still plenty of bugs issues, but a very annoying one is that if I have notifications and turn off the display, after a few seconds it turns on (only black and white) and off, on and off, a many annoying times.

If I turn my display off, I want it to be off, regardless of notifications I haven't seen/dismissed. I suppose it is consuming a lot of battery since the display is being on much more often than the usual.

I could not find anything regarding this issue on the Internet.

Anyone has seen it before/can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I once encountered similar behavior which was triggered by **Ambient Display** feature inside **Settings**. There is a guide on OnePlus Forums [here](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/guide-how-to-improve-battery-life-on-cos12-yng1tas17l.305907/) (see *Usage of Privacy Guard & Built in Settings (All Users)*) which mentions this:

> **Ambient Display** – this is again another option under the Display section of the Settings, when turned on (is ON by default) splashes notifications on the lock screen in black & white, every time you grab your phone off a table or something. This is a built in feature of Android Lollipop and is very useful. However, it is not that every time you grab the phone you wanna view notifications. You could be heading some where and want to keep the phone in your pocket or mounting the phone onto your car dashboard and the list goes on. So every time you do this, the ambient display comes and goes. While this may not eat up a whole lot of battery, turning this off will do something good.

Now that you know its under **Settings** →  **Display & lights** , you may try unchecking it and see if the issue ends. I had this issue when I flashed Lollipop and it ended right after unchecking it.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the issue! It seems it uses accelerometer data to infer whether the phone was grabbed or not, but it must be pretty inaccurate as I left it on the table and it would turn the display on and off a couple of times.

Comment: It also seems to do it when new notifications come in (and seems to cycle a couple of times before finally staying off). I've observed this on a CyanogenMod 12.1 nightly (based on Lollipop 5.1; 6/24 build for Sprint Galaxy S3) so I think it's an Android 5.x thing.

It'd be nice if they divorced the "turn on and off multiple times when you get a notification" option from the "wake up when you move your phone if you have notifications" option. I might actually like the latter. The former is flat-out annoying though when my phone is sitting on my desk in sight and keeps blinking.

Comment: @DoktorJ Thanks for the additional information. You can try filing your said opinion as a feature request [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_The_JIRA_project_management_system). You can see [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2267445) as well to know a bit more about feature-request.