# Active lockscreen and do no disturb mode

Tags: lock-screens, 6.0-marshmallow

Recently got a Nexus 5X with Android 6.0.1. Non-root.

The setting under **"Display -> Active Lockscreen"** toggles whether to **"wake the screen when I pick up the device or receives messages"**. I like these featues.

But even though I turn on **"Do not disturb"** from notification drawer, the screen wakes up when I pick up the device. I would like to disable this*.

Can I have it my way without rooting?
(Text is loosely translated from danish)

*I like listening to podcasts and audiobooks late at night to help me sleep. The slightest movement lights up the screen which becomes quite irritating.

Comment: Are you referring to [Ambient Display](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/108548/96277)?

Comment: Yes it is the ambient display. If I could just get lock screen notifications without ambient display that would be okay as well.